# I can't figure out why this is giving me a runtime error 9 (yes, the files are present and loaded)

Tags: vba, excel

```
Sub CopyColumnWidths(FileName1, SheetName1, FileName2, SheetName2)
    ColumnNumber = 1
    Check = WorksheetFunction.CountA(Workbooks(FileName1).Sheets(SheetName1).Columns(ColumnNumber))
    Do While Check > 0
        ColumnLetter = LastColumnLetter(ColumnNumber)
        Workbooks(FileName2).Sheets(SheetName2).Columns(ColumnNumber).ColumnWidth = Workbooks(FileName1).Sheets(SheetName1).Columns(ColumnNumber).ColumnWidth
        ColumnNumber = ColumnNumber + 1
        Check = WorksheetFunction.CountA(Workbooks(FileName1).Sheets(SheetName1).Range(ColumnLetter & ":" & ColumnLetter))
    Loop
End Sub
```

Ok, so this is my code. I have verified that all the file names and sheet names are present and accounted for in the same instance of Excel. I have checked for misspellings, extra characters, and 'invisible' characters and none are present.

I tried, for troubleshooting purposes, putting in a Workbooks(FileName1).Activate and it wouldn't work either. In different code that particular file does get hidden, but at the time this code is executed that workbook is visible and present.

For the life of me I cannot figure out why this is breaking and could use a hand.

This is running on Excel 2013, 64-bit if it matters.

------- More Info

FileName1 is "Original Datasheet.xlsx"
FileName2 is "Split Datasheet.xlsx"
SheetName1 (and SheetName2) are "1a. Contents"

When I try to activate FileName2, it works. When I try to activate FileName1, it fails. The sheet names don't matter, it doesn't 'see' FileName1, even though it is present and I can select it in the 'Switch Windows' dropdown.

Repeating again for those who didn't read the title the first time: Yes, all files are loaded in the same instance of Excel. All Files Are Present.

Comment: Is the `Filename1` workbook already open in the application?  You should be able to see it in the Workbooks collection using Watch or Debug.

Comment: Are `FileName1` and `SheetName1` both `String` variables?  Does `FileName1` only include the base filename (with extension) or do you have the full path in that variable too?  Perhaps put a `Debug.Print FileName1` into your code before the line that is crashing.

Comment: What are you passing to that procedure? The parameters are all implicitly `Variant`, so it will happily take whatever you throw at it. If that's meant to be names, defined them `As String`. If they're meant to be objects, define them as `Workbook` and `Worksheet` objects.

Comment: Just to be clear: nobody can answer this question without making assumptions, until you [edit] to clarify what you're feeding that procedure with.

Comment: Start by figuring out if it's the filename or the sheet  reference which is wrong: it's not possible to tell when you have them both in one line, so split that up or pull out `Workbooks(FileName1)` into a `With...End With` wrapper.

Comment: What is error message?

Comment: FYI - to get rid of `ColumnLetter` you can use `Check = WorksheetFunction.CountA(Workbooks(FileName1).Sheets(SheetName1).Columns(ColumnNumber))`.  I made that modification (because I didn't have the `LastColumnLetter` function, which I assume takes `ColumnNumber` and returns the "letter" of the column one column to the right) and your function worked for me - i.e. it set the column widths on a sheet based on the column widths of another sheet, for each column that had at least 2 non-empty cells in the "source" sheet, stopping when it found a column with 1 or 0 cells.

Comment: @Andy - Title says it is runtime error 9.

Comment: `letter1 = "A"
    letter2 = "B"
    Check = WorksheetFunction.CountA(Workbooks("Book1").Sheets("Sheet1").Range(letter1 & ":" & letter2))` this worked,no error message.

Comment: @RBarryYoung Yes, as stated in the title, all files are loaded and visible.

Comment: @YowE3K The post has been edited with the string contents.

Comment: @Mat'sMug The post has been edited with the string contents.

Comment: @TimWilliams The post has been edited with results.

Comment: Before anyone asks me to post all the code, there are thousands of lines of code in all this. This one subroutine is the only one breaking. Is it possible that previous code that hides the window for FIleName1 but later unhides it is messing things up? I had to do that because Excel kept putting data on the wrong workbook unless I hid it.

Comment: Side Note: "files are present and loaded" is sufficiently ambiguous to not really mean anything.  "Open in the Excel application, and visible as a worksheet" may or may not be what was intended by "present and loaded".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have been looking at this too long.

FileName1 was coming across as "Orignial Datasheet.xlsx" not "Original Datasheet.xlsx"

That is why it wasn't connecting. My mistake, sorry for bothering everyone.

Comment: Good for you. I hope you still take a moment to read my answer though, because the way your code is written is just asking for more of such errors to happen. Fix the actual code problem, not just the typos.

Comment: In your OP, you had said: **"I have verified that all the file names and sheet names are present and accounted for in the same instance of Excel. I have checked for misspellings, extra characters, and 'invisible' characters and none are present."** And i post this comment not to rub it in, but to help you appreciate why Mat's comments are so important. We all make silly mistakes. That's what we do. Well structured code will help you spot your exact error much quicker, and then you will save sooo much time.

Answer (score 2):

I don't have your answer, but runtime error 9 sounds a lot like one of these values isn't what you think it is - and with the code you have it's hard to tell exactly where it's blowing up.

Start with turning this:

> ```
> Sub CopyColumnWidths(FileName1, SheetName1, FileName2, SheetName2)
> ```

into this (assuming the procedure is called from within the same module - if it's called from another module, make it `Public Sub`):

```
Private Sub CopyColumnWidths(ByVal FileName1 As String, ByVal SheetName1 As String, ByVal FileName2 As String, ByVal SheetName2 As String)
```

Changing your signature to use `String` parameters passed *by value* shouldn't break your code in any way, but makes things more explicit and therefore improves readability and makes your intent clearer.

Moving on.

> ```
> ColumnNumber = 1
> ```

Where's that coming from? Declare it. Stick `Option Explicit` at the top of your module, and then **declare every variable** until your code compiles again (Option Explicit will make VBA refuse to compile code that uses undeclared variables).

```
Dim ColumnNumber As Long
ColumnNumber = 1
```

Now that we know `ColumnNumber` and `Check` are local variables declared in the same scope (right?), we move on:

```
Dim Check As Long
Check = WorksheetFunction.CountA(Workbooks(FileName1).Sheets(SheetName1).Columns(ColumnNumber))
```

This line is doing too many things: we don't know that `Workbooks(FileName1)` is succeeding, and we don't know that its `Sheets(SheetName1)` is succeeding either - yet we call its `Columns` member regardless, assuming blue skies and sunshine.

Don't assume blue skies and sunshine.

Break it down.

```
Dim sourceBook As Workbook
Set sourceBook = Workbooks(FileName1)

Dim sourceSheet As Worksheet
Set sourceSheet = sourceBook.Worksheets(SheetName1)

Check = WorksheetFunction.CountA(sourceSheet.Columns(ColumnNumber))
```

If your code runs up to that point, your problem is half-solved - you have the same issue here, and you're fetching the same `Workbook` and `Worksheet` objects *again* - instead, *break it down*, assign local object variables, and *reuse them*:

> ```
> Workbooks(FileName2).Sheets(SheetName2).Columns(ColumnNumber).ColumnWidth = Workbooks(FileName1).Sheets(SheetName1).Columns(ColumnNumber).ColumnWidth
> ```

```
Dim destinationBook As Workbook
Set destinationBook = Workbooks(FileName2)

Dim destinationSheet As Worksheet
Set destinationSheet = destinationBook(SheetName2)

destinationSheet.Columns(ColumnNumber).ColumnWidth = sourceSheet.Columns(ColumnNumber).ColumnWidth

ColumnNumber = ColumnNumber + 1
Check = WorksheetFunction.CountA(sourceSheet.Range(ColumnLetter & ":" & ColumnLetter))
```

Step through (<kbd>F8</kbd>) this code line by line, then you'll know exactly which instruction is blowing up. Cramming everything into as few code lines as possible and chaining 2, 3, 4 member accesses *assuming it will "just work"* makes it nearly impossible to know that.

---

> *Is it possible that previous code that hides the window for FIleName1 but later unhides it is messing things up? I had to do that because **Excel kept putting data on the wrong workbook unless I hid it**.*

This sounds like you have code (elsewhere?) that works off `ActiveSheet`, or `ActiveWorkbook`, explicitly or (more likely?) implicitly.

If you find yourself using unqualified `Range`, `Cells`, `Rows`, `Columns` or `Names` calls, you're implicitly referring to the active sheet. Replace them with explicitly qualified member calls using the worksheet object you mean to refer to. There's no magic, Excel (VBA actually) can't guess your intentions; it doesn't "keep putting data on the wrong workbook" - it puts data exactly where you tell it to put it. Hiding the workbook is just a terribly bad work-around: you're still not telling it *explicitly* where you mean to put it.